# PHP force_download is downloading file with filename specified but calling it 'file.pdf'

Tags: php, codeigniter, force-download

I am using force_download and everything works well except for the file being named 'file.pdf' and not 'Daily_delivery_sheet.pdf'.  The pdf looks correct, it's just the filename that is wrong.  I am stumped as to why this is happening.

In the next function in the same file, the code is exactly the same and it is working perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
$pdf = $mcccpdf->getPdf($data);
$this->load->helper('download');
$filename = 'Daily_delivery_sheet.pdf';
force_download($filename, $pdf);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that another programmer put `$pdfobj->ezStream( array('compress' => 0 ) );` where the PDF was being generated and that was the cause of the problem. I removed it and everything works perfectly now.